# Алгоритм разделения строки по два элемента

Tags: python, алгоритм

Например, есть строка `a1b2c3d4f5`, а должно получиться `['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4', 'f5']`

Строка всегда будет четной длины

Мне интересно какие есть эффективные способы получить такой результат.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используя регулярные выражения (RegEx):

```
import re

In [12]: re.findall(r'.{2}', text)
Out[12]: ['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4', 'f5']
```

для двух символов можно [использовать более короткий ваниант - `'..'` как посоветовал @Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704455/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0/704459#comment1048207_704459)

```
In [13]: re.findall(r'..', text)
Out[13]: ['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4', 'f5']
```

---

Еще один вариант:

```
n = 2
[text[start : start+n] for start in range(0, len(text), n)]
```

Пример:

```
In [33]: [text[start : start+n] for start in range(0, len(text), n)]
Out[33]: ['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4', 'f5']
```

Comment: Здорово выглядит :)

Comment: Я бы использовал `..` вместо `.{2}`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я сначала так и сделал, но потом подумал о варианте с тремя+ точками и решил сделать так как выглядит сейчас...

Answer (score 5):

Прикладываю свой пример через `zip` и использование среза с шагом:

```
text = 'a1b2c3d4f5'
print([a + b for a, b in zip(text[::2], text[1::2])])
# ['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4', 'f5']
```